# What is an elegant way to initialize multiple react-live components from a static website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages, static-site, hugo

I'm currently creating a react component library that i want to provide as an `npm` package. I also want to provide a documentation that features fancy live rendering of the available components on e.g. github pages.

For the live editing feature i'm planning to use [react-live](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-live) which provides multiple react components to display a live editor and a preview. See an example from the [styled-components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#media-templates) how this looks like.

The `react-live` component accepts a string `code` containing the initial code that should be displayed in the editor and a list of components `scope` that can be used inside the live editor.

Now i want to use [gohugo](https://gohugo.io/) or a similar static site generator to deploy my documentation. I thought i could maybe provide a `<div>` inside my static site that has a special class `react-live-demo` and i will get these containers with `document.getElementsByClassName('react-live-demo')`, loop over them and render the react-live component into it.

I created a code snippet that shows a little example:

```js
const {LiveProvider, LiveEditor, LiveError, LivePreview} = window['react-live'];

// a random component that i want to render in the live editor
const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>react live demo</h1>
    <p>This is a component from the script tag.</p>
  </div>
);

// a wrapper for the react-live editor
const Editor = ({code, scope}) => (
  <LiveProvider code={code} scope={scope}>
    <div className="live-example row">
      <div className="col-xs">
        <LiveEditor />
        <LiveError />
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs">
        <LivePreview />
      </div>
    </div>
  </LiveProvider>
);

// get all containers that have the initial code as innerHTML
const examples = document.querySelectorAll('script[data-name="react-live"]');

examples.forEach(example => {
  // insert a new div before the script tag
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  example.parentNode.insertBefore(container, example.nextSibling);
  
  // render the editor with the code from the script tag
  const code = example.innerHTML.trim();
  ReactDOM.render(<Editor code={code} scope={{MyComponent}} />, container);
});
```

```css
.static-content {
  background-color: papayawhip;
}

.live-example {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.react-live-demo.code {
  display: none;
}

.invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="static-content">HERE IS SOME STATIC HTML CONTENT</p>

<script type="text/html" data-name="react-live">
<div>
  <h1>react live demo</h1>
  <p>This code is editable.</p>
</div>
</script>

<p class="static-content">SOME MORE STATIC HTML CONTENT</p>

<script type="text/html" data-name="react-live">
<MyComponent />
</script>





<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-live@1.7.0/dist/react-live.min.js"></script>
```

**The question is now:**

How do embed the code string into my static site so that i can grab it with my js code and pass it to my react-live component?

I thought about `<pre>` or something like that. Or should i just embed it as inner html and read that? But then it would be displayed for short when the react component hasn't rendered yet. Or should i use some sort of script tag and make it available as globals? **The key goal is to make it as easy as possible to add live editing examples to the documentation without touching any javascript code.**

However if i pass something like `<MyComponent />` as innerHTML this does of course not work as you can see in the code snippet.

Any best practice for that use case appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Based on the suggestion of [@Daniel Alexandrov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131825/5005177) i edited the code snippet. The solution now reads the `innerHTML` of script tags with `type="text/html` set and creates a `<div>` container to insert the editor. This seems to work quite well. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best choice is to use the `<script>` tag with a custom type attribute. Take a look at the [Knockout.js template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) which uses `type="text/html` or the Angular `<script type="text/ng-template">`

This way the browser will ignore the script tag completely, because it doesn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: Yeah that sounds promising. I will try that and update my snippet if it works.

Comment: Okay so i updated my snippet using your suggestions. Seems to work :) If nobody comes up with a better solution in the next 24 hours i will mark that as the accepted answer.